# How to set system variables in start-up scripts

Tags: bash, systemd

I'm controlling 8 servos using the PWM outputs on the BeagleBone.  On start-up the names of the PWMs are dynamically assigned so they vary from boot to boot, so to know which pin matches which PWM I've written this script:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    # match BeagleBone PWMCHIP{n} with available pwm controllers
    for i in $(/bin/ls /sys/class/pwm); do
        link=$(/bin/readlink /sys/class/pwm/$i)
        case "$link" in
            *48300100*) BBPWM0=$i;;
            *48300200*) BBPWM1=$i;;
            *48302200*) BBPWM2=$i;;
            *48304100*) BBPWM3=$i;;
            *48304200*) BBPWM4=$i;;
        esac
    done

    export BBPWM0
    export BBPWM1
    export BBPWM2
    export BBPWM3
    export BBPWM4

    echo "PWM0 = $BBPWM0" > /home/ormund/servo.log

    /home/ormund/servo-server
```

The system works when I start it from the command line, the servo-server listens on a network port and moves the servos correctly in response to remote commands, but if I start this from systemd at boot, it fails, the BBPWM0 is a null string and the server cant start.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The script looks fine, maybe the problem is that it's running before `/sys/class/pwm` is filled in.

Comment: You should use globs instead of command substitution with `ls`: `for i in /sys/class/pwm/*; do ...`

Comment: Barmar, you are right.  I added a test for the existence of "pwmchipN" in the /sys/class/pwm/ directory and delay until it exist, now the system works, thanks.